# How do I filter a managed object entity with multiple conditions

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I may be thinking about this the wrong way..

I have a search/filter function working on an entity. But I want to be able to filter on a couple of criteria..

I have this:

```
for (WordEntity *word in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
{
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [word.greekText isEqualToString:searchText ])
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [word.greekText compare:searchText
                                               options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {

            [self.searchResults addObject:word];
        }
    }
```

but I want the filter to capture both english and greek text. How do I best do that? Thanks

UPDATED

Apologies, but I still can't get this to work.. I've opened it up again..

As suggested, I've change the code as follows:

```
 [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
  NSLog(@"predicating");

NSPredicate *englishTextPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"englishText CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
NSLog(@"eng pred: %@", englishTextPredicate);

NSLog(@"search text: %@", searchText);


 [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:englishTextPredicate];
 NSArray *fetchedData = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

 self.searchResults = [fetchedData copy];
 NSLog(@"search count: %i", self.searchResults.count);
```

But this produces the following output.

```
2014-08-03 07:31:40.846 GuessGreek[16535:425669] Card Count is: 651
2014-08-03 07:31:54.495 GuessGreek[16535:425669] -[WordViewController searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:]
2014-08-03 07:31:54.495 GuessGreek[16535:425669] -[WordViewController filterContentForSearchText:scope:]
2014-08-03 07:31:54.496 GuessGreek[16535:425669] predicating
2014-08-03 07:31:54.496 GuessGreek[16535:425669] eng pred: englishText.text CONTAINS[cd] "o"
2014-08-03 07:31:54.496 GuessGreek[16535:425669] search text: o
2014-08-03 07:31:54.497 GuessGreek[16535:425669] search count: 651
```

[image]

This is a screenshot of the words.. Clearly, the first two words do not have an "o"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using a predicate and adding the appropriate criteria to that?

Comment: I know how to make the predicate, but I couldn't get the predicate to work with NSComparisonResult. Again, maybe I'm thinking of this the wrong way..

Comment: You would use the predicate directly to filter an array, or, better in a number of ways, fetch from the data store (directly or by updating your FRC)

Comment: Could you point me to a code snippet so I can see how to do this? I would prefer the latter option. I just can't figure what methods to use.

Comment: oops. found it...  NSArray *fetchedData = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

Answer (score 2):

Using a predicate would be simpler. You can use a compound predicate to search for two things.

```
NSPredicate * pred1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"greekText == %@", searchText];
NSPredicate * pred2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"englishText == %@", searchText];
NSPredicate * compPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pred1,pred2,nil]];
[YourFetchRequestName setPredicate:compPred];
```

and then executing your fetch request would only give what you want.

```
self.searchResults = [yourContext executeFetchRequest:YourFetchRequestName error:&error];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks !! That's great. I was missing this though too:  NSArray *fetchedData = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, this will only return entities with both greekText and englishText equal to the searchText... is that what you want? If you want one or the other you may need to do two requests.

Comment: that's what I"m finding. I want to be able to search for either a greek word or an english one... I will  try the orPredicate

Comment: sorry, I had to open this up again. I've simplified the predicate to just look in one field..

Comment: In regards to your updated question... where are you executing your fetch request? You're just calling fetchedObjects, which I don't think will be updated to match your predicate until you call the request again. What happens if you replace the line: "NSArray *fetchedData = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];" with : "NSArray *fetchedData = [self.fetchedResultsController executeFetchRequest:self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest error:&error];" ?

Comment: Also, I hadn't used it before when I answered, but I realized you can use an "OR" inside a predicate. So you can change the predicate format to: @"(englishText CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (greekText CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText

Comment: This is what I found too. If you would make this an answer, I'll close it out. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works well I think:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
   NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    for (WordEntity *word in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
    NSRange greekResult  = [word.greekText rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange englishResult = [word.englishText rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];

        if ( greekResult.location != NSNotFound || englishResult.location != NSNotFound ) {

            [self.searchResults addObject:word];
        }
```